# Chrome download doesn't display correctly

Tags: google-chrome

I've uninstalled Chrome for display issues twice now.

When I launch Chrome, a blank screen comes up with a frown face on the tab header. I can not go to any site - it doesn't open. I try use the drop down menu on the right to go to the settings page, it or the others will not open.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a chrome issue. Seems broader, like malware, or a corrupt userdata file. Try running malwarebytes and adware remover. By this, I'm saying, of my knowledge of chrome, it wouldn't normally do this unless something external to the program forces it to.

Comment: Does it behave the same when you open a new incognito window? Are you on windows,linux,osx?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your proxy settings? It may be set up to use proxy when you don't. Go to Settings > Advanced Settings > Under Network click on change proxy settings. Then click on LAN settings and uncheck the box that says to use proxy settings.